# How does Visual Studio 2017 open the browser for a debugging session?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

Does it use an internal `Process.Start`, or does it run a command line? My VS2017 RTM works OK with Chrome most of the time, then randomly it gives an error saying `Couldn't start program http://localhost...`.

Then I have to switch back to Edge, have it open Edge, and paste the URL into Chrome so I can use the dev tools I prefer. I'd like to somehow track any error that may occur when VS tries to start Chrome, and if it uses a command line, maybe I can capture that somehow and run it manually to debug why Chrome won't open.

Comment: Maybe this is an RTM related issue, it's working for me with the latest version of Visual Studio (15.0.0+26228.9) Chrome always launches, as for the question you could check using Process Explorer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio debugger launches the selected browser using the Windows API CreateProcess. For more context on how a typical debug engine would call this, see the Debug Engine [sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Visual-Studio-Debug-Engine-c2e21c0e/sourcecode?fileId=123959&pathId=2024998684) and search for the method called LaunchProcess.

Disclaimer: I work on the Visual Studio debugger team at Microsoft.